# IIS 6 & Web Deploy 3.5 - ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN

Tags: iis, webdeploy

I've been trying to use Web Deploy 3.5 to deploy an application to an IIS 6 web server without any luck.

I am connecting using a domain service account that is an administrator of the remote server, but when I attempt to deploy (or validate the connection in VS2012) I receive a "ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN" error instead.

[image: Visual Studio error]

I read that Web Deploy 2.0 had a bug in it where a domain user account could not be used, but surely that's fixed by now? Right?

Has anyone had any luck with IIS 6.0, Web Deploy 3.5 and domain user accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing. It looks like that error message is also returned if the password is incorrect.

Oh well, you live and learn!

Comment: Embarrassing for you or MS? I had the same issue but realized I typed the pw wrong. However, had I not known that, the error message would have mislead me.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone else trying this (with the right password ;-) , there is an issue using non domain accounts that gives this message, and the link in the error wasn't much use for me....

There is a regedit (yes, I know it's dirty, but this was a dev machine), which gets this working.... I'd tried everything from the MS link with adding users to additional groups etc, but still didn't work, the solution below did though.

Take a look at http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2010/10/29/401-not-authorized-for-msdeploy%E2%80%8F-msdeployagentservice/

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: The user's password has expired.

Either

1. go into the "local users" within computer management and make sure **Password never expires** is checked, OR
2. run this command for that user:  `WMIC USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name='YOUR-USERNAME-HERE'" SET PasswordExpires=FALSE`